# Rownumberer does increment past the number 1 on my Ext.grid.ColumnModel rows

Tags: extjs

I am not able to get the rownumberer to count my rows.  I just get the number 1 for each row and not 1, 2, 3, and so on.  Where am I going wrong?  Thanks for the help.

```
        var iLineItemCM = new Ext.grid.ColumnModel([
    new Ext.grid.RowNumberer(),
{
    id:'i_line_item_name',
    header: "Line Item Name",
    dataIndex: 'i_line_item_name',
    width: 280,
    editor: new Ext.form.TextArea({
        allowBlank: false
    })
}
,{
    header: "Amount",
    dataIndex: 'i_line_item_amt',
    width: 80,
    align: 'right',
    renderer: 'usMoney',
    editor: new Ext.form.NumberField({
        allowBlank: false,
        allowNegative: false,
        maxValue: 100000
    })
}
]);
```

Comment: This is used for an EditorGridPanel.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when using a grid panel and adding records one at a time at run time. The row numberer gets the numbers from the record index and I had to manually tell each record what its index was going to be

```
store.load(function(records, operation, success) {
            if (success) {
                // set the index on the record so that the rows will be numbered correctly.
                // this is a known bug in extjs when adding records dynamically
                records[0].index = me.current_count;
                me.current_count++;
                // There is only 1 compound record returned
                me.getGrid().getStore().add(records[0]);
```